# C# Reflect unknown child type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class:

```
public class Chid1 : Parent{
    public string var1{get;set;}
    public string var2{get;set;}
}

public class Chid2 : Parent{
    public string var3{get;set;}
    public string var4{get;set;}
}
```

I am collecting some data from an xml file and I need to setup these classes.

So this is what I can do for now:

```
string child = "Chid1";//from the xml
Parent instance = (Parent)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(child ) , ...);
```

Since Parent does not containg details about the childs, I cant do:

```
instance.var1 = "Some text from the XML";
```

Is there any solution here of setting up the childs via strings like:

```
Activator.SetParan(instance,"var1" , "Some text from the XML");
```

Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using `dynamic` here.  It would make the code much simpler.

```
dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(child ) , ...);
instance.var1 = "some text from the XML";
```

Additionally is there a reason you're not using a known serialization engine.  If you are simply serializing objects to an from an XML stream there are a number of existing solutions that would make your life easier

- [.Net XML serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx)
- [Protobuf for .Net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/protobuf-net/ServiceModel/XmlProtoSerializer.cs?r=406)

Comment: The is sounds like a good solution but I still have a problem. `var1` is also dinamic text that comming from the xml So I dont have it while i code, only when I pharse, thanks

Comment: @yosmishan if the name itself is generic then very likely you will need to drop down to reflection then or go with an existing serialization framework.

Comment: I dont understand, can you give me a link for a tutorial? thanks for your help

Comment: @yosmishan try the following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Give the child classes a constructor and then supply the arguments through the second argument to Activator.CreateInstance, which takes constructor args as params object[]:

```
 public class Child1 : Parent
 {     
       public Child1(string _var1, string _var2) 
       {
            this.var1 = _var1;
            this.var2 = _var2
       }

       public string var1 { get; set;}     
       public string var2 { get; set;} 
 }

 Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Child1), new object[] { "var1", "var2" });
```